# Golden Sun data transfer to The Lost Age on Wii U virtual console

Tags: wii-u, virtual-console, golden-sun, golden-sun-the-lost-age

Does the virtual console version of the game have a new data transfer system, or will I have to manually type the password again once I get The Lost Age?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have to type the password. The Golden Sun games on the Wii U are run on a special emulator, so it essentially becomes a GBA for it... there isn't a way in the Wii U menu to transfer all the data.
Just do the short bronze password. The stats that get passed over when you use the silver one are just the extra stat points you got if you used the items like Mint, Apple and Hard Nut etc on your party, and that stupid ass long Gold code for the items... the only item really worth transferring is the Cleric's Ring, and even that isn't worth that 6 page long code. I remember I tried it once... took me well over 30 minutes to input the code and I must have made a mistake somewhere because it said it was invalid. :(
I then got hold of a GBA link cable and used my sister's GBA to transfer everything that way, and ended up selling all the weapons and armor I transferred as soon as I could anyway. Every single item you have at the end of GS1 is totally outclassed and useless by the time you get Isaac's group in GS2, so there's really no need to input anything other than the Bronze code, which luckily only takes a few seconds.

Also Psynergy bestowing items like the Force Orb ARE included in the Bronze code, so you'll be able to get everything in GS2.

Comment: I'm quite sure the Gold Password also transfers collected Djinns which some will be missing if you rely on the default data (which is why you still have Psynergy Items transfered when only using bronze). you need all of them in The Lost Age to access an optional Area for the final summon. also you can easily pass the first game and beat all optional bosses without using stat increasing items so you have horde them for when you create your main party

Comment: I bit the bullet and entered the full gold password yesterday. It went relatively smooth :P While Bronze does transfer Djinn, only Silver transfers the exact stats (when increased with stuff like Apple).